# Unable to add suggestion chips in google assistant inline on a particular intent

Tags: javascript, error-handling, actions-on-google

I have implemented the code, which works fine but as soon as I started to add code with addSugestions, error occurers. Anyone here please share your knowledge with code implementation through index.js

```
'use strict';

//Import the Dialogflow module from the Actions on Google client library//

const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');

//Import the firebase-functions package//

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

//Instantiate the Dialogflow client//

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

//Handle the create_name intent//

app.intent('create_name', (conv, {name}) => {

    //Construct the conversational response//

    conv.ask('Nice to meet you ' + name + '. Would you like to hear a joke?');
});




app.intent('create_yes', (conv) => {

    //Construct the conversational response//

    //conv.ask('Nice to meet you. Would you like to hear a joke?').addSuggestions(['0', '42', '100', 'Never mind']);

    conv.ask('Nice to meet you. Would you like to hear a joke?');
});





//Set the DialogflowApp object to handle the HTTPS POST request//

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding suggestions is done with a [`Suggestions`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_response.suggestions.html) object that you add with [`conv.add()`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation.conversation-1.html#add).

Something like this:

```
const {dialogflow,Suggestions} = require('actions-on-google');

// ...

app.intent( 'suggest', conv => {
  conv.add( 'Here are some suggestions' );
  conv.add( new Suggestions( ['one','two','whatever'] ) );
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion and code as I was missing the suggestion declaration. Many google action is going to come.